# Get JSON to print empty array.

Tags: php, arrays, json, actionscript-3, function

I'm new to php and not sure why the go-daddy server treats JSON data differently. 
When I host it locally on my computer in local host, when I want to echo empty JSON array, I simply put [] shown as below. But when I uploaded the code to go-daddy server and try it out it echoed an error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in...I'm wondering how can I put the JSON so it can echo [] when needed. Otherwise it will give "null" and when it parse into AS3, it turn into a JSON parse error.

```
if (!empty($output)){
        echo json_encode( $output );}
        else{
            echo json_encode( [] );
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because your webserver version must be less than 5.4. You are trying to use a [**new feature**](https://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) of PHP 5.4 called the  *short array syntax*

Use `echo json_encode(array());` instead of `echo json_encode( [] );`

[<kbd>Working Demo on PHP v 5.3</kbd>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JTRjL8)

Comment: Thanks for the info, i just went to the server and updated the version, now it works, i didnt know it was set to 5.3 before.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use this:

```
if (!empty($output)){
        echo json_encode( $output );}
        else{
            echo json_encode(array());
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

`[]` for arrays is only supported in php 5.4+.

So that means php is not a high enough version on your host, try asking them to upgrade to 5.4 or try `array();` instead of `[]`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(count(json_encode($jArrary,1))==0) {
echo "empty";
}
//or
if(empty(json_encode($jArrary,1))) {
echo "empty";
}
```

you can use this